# Python passing arguments through a chain of function calls

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the pythonic way to pass arguments down a chain function calls? Say I have the following function:

```
 def get_remainder(timeseries,freq, model='additive', item='residue'):

      if item == 'residue':
          return decompose(timeseries, freq=freq, model=model).residue
      elif item == 'trend':
          return decompose(timeseries, freq=freq, model=model).trend
```

For the purposes of this question the `decompose` function exists and is not important. It takes as model either a *multiplicative* or *additive* as strings. As you can see `get_remainder` returns either a residue or trend. So all in all we have four choices here. We can

- model='additive', item='trend'
- model='additive', item='residue'
- model='multiplicative', etc. .

The problem is `get_remainder` is the last call to in a chain:

```
def func1(data, params):
    # does something to data, maybe shape is different, maybe some elements deleted etc. 
    return func2(data, params)

def func2(data, params):
    # does something to data 
    return func3(data, params)

def func3(data, params):
    # does something to data 
    remainder = get_remainder(timeseries,freq, model=params['model'], item=params['residue']):
    # does something to remainder. 
    returns remainder <> data
```

where `<>` denotes some sort of operation involving remainder and data. I want to be able to get all the four types from the first function, `func1` so I have been passing `model` and `item` down the chain in the `params` argument.

But this seems very weird/un-pythonic to me. None of the middle functions use `model` and `item` directly (though `params` may include other argument) they just carry it along so the last function can use it.

What is a better way to do this?

Comment: you could create an object, and have `model`/``item` be instance members

Comment: The original `get_remainder` could look like this one liner: `return getattr(decompose(...), item)`

Comment: Is the result of only `func1` and `func2` alone always uninteresting? But as far as I know quite a few libraries use `**kwargs` to pass arguments on and on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `**kwargs` (keyword arguments) syntax.  Now you can call `func1` with any number of keyword arguments, which will be gathered into a dictionary called `params`.  When you call another function, you can unpack `params` using the dictionary unpacking syntax `**params`.  So `func2(data, **{"model": "additive"})` is the same as `func2(data, model="additive")`.

If a keyword argument is included in the function signature, it will nto be collected as part of `**params`.  For a function `def f(a=1, **kwargs)`, the call `f(**{"a": 2})` would leave `kwargs` empty.

```
def func1(data, **params):
    # does something to data, maybe shape is different, maybe some elements deleted etc. 
    return func2(data, **params)

def func2(data, **params):
    # does something to data 
    return func3(data, **params)

def func3(data, **params):
    # does something to data 
    remainder = get_remainder(timeseries,freq, **params)

def get_remainder(timeseries,freq, model='additive', item='residue'):
    if item == 'residue':
        return decompose(timeseries, freq=freq, model=model).residue
    elif item == 'trend':
        return decompose(timeseries, freq=freq, model=model).trend
```

Comment: Thanks! I recently heard about decorators in python. Would this problem be solvable using decorators or is `kwargs` the standard way to do this?

Comment: `kwargs` is definitely the standard way.  I can't think of a nice approach to this using decorators.